# Compare Two Files and Store Useful Information Individually Using Java

Tags: java, file

I am new in Java. I have written code to compare two data files. I want to store useful information by categories individually. Here is my code：

```
File file1 = new File ("C:\\Users\\manglai\\Desktop\\Day_20160101_20191118\\Day_20160101_20191118.csv");
File file2 = new File ("C:\\Users\\manglai\\Desktop\\Day_20160101_20191118\\Symbols.csv");

BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1)); 
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2)); 
String st1; 
String st2;
while ((st2= br2.readLine()) != null)
{
    while ((st1= br1.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(st1.matches(st2+"(.*)")){
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(st2+".CSV");
            fw.write(st1);
            System.out.println(st1);
        }
    }
    br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
}
```

It will create new CSV file, but not write anything to the file.

Comment: Did you flush your stream? To see the data you must flush the streams!

Comment: You are not closing the CSV file that you are creating. You need to call method [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close--)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try

```
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(st2+".CSV");
 fw.append(st1);
 fw.flush();
 fw.close();
```

please create "FileWriter fw " object outside the loop.

There are several ways to read and write CSV files in Java, the simplest being using Core Java components. Although this also leaves you more vulnerable to bugs and will be less robust than a proven third-party solution

https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csvs-in-java-with-apache-commons-csv/

https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csvs-in-java-with-opencsv/